# When I toggle from Vim mode in VS Code, my cursor changes to "line" type even though I had cursor set to block throughout VS code

Tags: vscodevim

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKYcY.png)I have

```
"editor.cursorStyle": "block"
```

in **settings.json**  but whenever I toggle back from Vim mode, my cursor changes to "line" automatically. In Vim it is set to block and line depending on the mode I am in. Is this a bug or is there any solution for this. I want my cursor to always be block styled.

I tried searching issues raised in repository for VSCodeVim , stackOVerflow. Nothing.